# Git undo reverting file to master

Tags: git

I had a file on a branch that I thought I wanted to revert to its state in master, so I did:

```
git checkout origin/master [filename]
```

Then I realized I didn't want to do this. How do I undo this?

Comment: `git checkout HEAD -- [filename]` would be the reverse operation. `HEAD` is not necessary (because implied), I added for clarity.`

Comment: But uncommitted changes have gone for good.

Comment: @phd Yes unfortunately. They've been wiped by the first checkout indeed.

Comment: (unless it was, by a miraculous hand, added into the index before *the checkout of hell*)

Comment: Or preserved in history/undo buffers of an editor/IDE.

Comment: *Uncommitted* files are not in Git. Being not-in, it's not possible to get them back out.

Answer (score 0):

Note: reverting a file content is best done with [git restore](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore)

```
git restore --staged --worktree  -- filename
```

But, as commented, uncommitted changes are still lost.
Which means you would need to check with your IDE to recreate lost changes.
For instance, VSCode, has a **timeline view** which provides a local history of said file, allowing you to restore a past content (even when not saved in a Git commit)

The other option is (depending on your OS) to check if you had [activated Time Machine on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201250) for instance.